# Load Google Cloud Storage data into bigtable

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

Is there an easy way or example to load `Google Cloud Storage` data into `bigtable`?

I have lots of `json` files generated by pyspark and i wish to load data into `bigtable`.

But I can not find an easy way to do that!

I have tried the `python` code from [google-cloud-python](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-python-hello) and it work fined, but it just read data line by line into bigtable which was strange for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please send me that modified python code, I have a same requirenment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple tool to read data in Cloud Bigtable.  Here are some options:

1. Import the files using [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/dataflow-hbase).  This requires java development, and learning the Dataflow programming model.
2. Use Python (possibly with Pyspark) to read those json files, and write to Cloud Bigtable using a method called [mutate_rows](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/table.html#google.cloud.bigtable.table.Table.mutate_rows) which write to Bigtable in bulk.

FYI, I work on the Cloud Bigtable team.  I'm a Java developer, so I opt for #1.  Our team has been working to improve our python experience.  The extended team recently added some reliability improvements to make sure that mutate_rows is resilient for large jobs.  We do not yet have any good examples of integrating with PySpark or [Apache Beam's python SDK](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python/), but they are on our radar.

Comment: Hi, @Solomon, thanks for sharing the experience of your team. I have tried to use Dataflow to do that. I think I do not really know about how to use Dataflow on gcp.  By the way, documents of gcp are always confuse me!! ha..ha..

Comment: Here are some examples using Dataflow with Cloud Bigtable: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/dataflow-connector-examples

Comment: I will try it later. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Does it have Python Support now?

Comment: I believe that writing works: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigtableio.py#L32.  Reading is in progress: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/11295