# How to transfer huge json from instance to Bigtable in goole cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I have almost 1 million JSON file in my instance, I want to build a database using Bigtable. How can I do that using Python?

Comment: Note that this question is to broad and you should do the research and have something working already and than show what have you done and at what point you got stuck. Anyway I am providing you an answer to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started I suggest you to take a look at this [Python Hello World](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-python-hello) example and Stack Overflov case [Load Google Cloud Storage data into bigtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345794/load-google-cloud-storage-data-into-bigtable).